# QT + XSB prolog: "read access violation at 0x0"

Tags: c++, qt, prolog, qt-creator, xsb

I want to use XSB prolog in QT application.
I wrote:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "cinterf.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize xsb */
    xsb_init_string((char*)("c:/Program Files (x86)/XSB -n"));
    char s[100] = "consult('g:/develop/qt/paid/kb').";
    int r = xsb_command_string(s);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But it crashes with an error message "read access violation at 0x0 ...".
What is the problem and how to fix it?
[image: The error]]

Comment: The error occurs in xsb_command_string function.

Comment: Suggest that you ask on the QT forums concerning xsb interfaces.

Comment: Does the exception also occur when you remove the Qt parts? You could use `std::cout` in the beginning. Then you know if the error is related to Xsb or Qt

Comment: I did not test it. I think it's no matter what C++ code is around XSB calls. It's just the problem within XSB I guess.